# Feeds import from RSS changing dates to current timestamp

Tags: datetime, feeds

I'm trying to import some old news items from a legacy site/system.

Using feeds importer to get the content from an RSS feed.

All works fine except the published date value gets rewritten to the timestamp at point of import. I can't find an option to change this behaviour, even using the 'tamper' module doesn't seem to assist.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Tamper module doing it, looks like you not configure it properly.

Comment: Uninstalled Tamper & it still happens...

Comment: Can you show how you configure tamper?

Comment: As mentioned tamper uninstalled and the problem persisted. It was an issue with the source RSS date formats.

Comment: May be I comment above incorrectly, Tamper module should convert date format 1 to date format 2 (dependly what you set on Date Field settings). So no required disable Tamper, show me how you setup it (screenshot or any other)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it wasn't Feeds itself but rather the old site's RSS being invalid.
If the simplePie parser used by Feeds can't find a properly formatted `<pubDate>` value it defaults to a current timestamp.